# Python Regular Expression - Matching Newlines with Numerous Matches

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to create a form of dictionary parser. In a text file, I have text in the following format:

```
<topic>some_title1:<start>
test_text<end>

<topic>title_2:<start>
test1
test2<end>
```

In each case, `<topic>` denotes a key, and the text between `<start>` and `<end>` is the value. The key is always a single line, whereas the value may (and most likely will) be more than one line.

My regex is as follows:

```
p = re.compile("<topic>(.+):<start>\n(.+)<end>")
```

I am using `p.findall(data)` to get the key/value pairs.

Without `re.DOTALL`, I only get one match, which is the first (`some_title1` with a value of `test_text`). However, I need both matches.

So, I tried using `re.DOTALL`.

This, on the other hand, also gives one match, but not correctly:

`some_title1:<start>\ntest_text<end>\n\n<topic>title_2` with a corresponding value of `test1\ntest2`.

How can I fix this? I (hopefully) want to maintain the tag-like structure.

Comment: Can you change the way your input file look like? It would be much easier to if your file was in xml format. If so, you can use [lxml](http://lxml.de/) and/or [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) to work with your data in a much easier way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this:

```
>>> import re
>>> t = '''<topic>some_title1:<start>
test_text<end>

<topic>title_2:<start>
test1
test2
<end>'''
>>> q = re.findall(r'<topic>([^:<]+?):<start>([^<]+?)<end>', t)
[('some_title1', '\ntest_text'), ('title_2', '\ntest1\ntest2\n')]
>>> dict(q)
{'some_title1': '\ntest_text', 'title_2': '\ntest1\ntest2\n'}
```

Or in one line:

```
>>> dict(re.findall(r'<topic>([^:<]+?):<start>([^<]+?)<end>', t))
{'some_title1': '\ntest_text', 'title_2': '\ntest1\ntest2\n'}
```

This captures multiple-lined values. Of course, xml would be much nicer to work with here. But in light of the structure of your data, the key seems to be to collect text between `>` and `<` by matching any character other than `<`. In other words, your key should match this group: `([^:<]+?)`. And your value should match this group: `([^<]+?)`.

Comment: @Aaron Hall From the docs: 'The dict() constructor builds dictionaries directly from sequences of key-value pairs.' Any sequence of key-value pairs can be converted to a dict.

Answer (score 2):

If you can represent your data in another way, this would be much easier. Say that you represent your data like this:

```
<topic title="some title1">test_text1</topic>
<topic title="some title2">test_text2</topic>
```

Accessing title and content is easy now using [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

xml = """
    <topic title="some title1">test_text1</topic>
    <topic title="some title2">test_text2</topic>
    """

soup = BeautifulSoup(xml)
for topic in soup.find_all('topic'):
    print topic['title'], topic.text
```

This will yield

```
some title1 test_text1
some title2 test_text2
```